# Graphic of binary variable in R

Tags: r

I would like to plot a simple graphic. I have a dat set with n rowns and k columns, in which each row has a a sequence of 0 and 1. I would like to plot exactly this sequence for all rows.

Actually I want to reproduce the figure 24.1, p. 516, of Gelman and Hill's book (Data aAnalysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models). I suspect that he made the graphic in Latex, but it seems quite ridiculous that I'm not able to repplicate this simple graphic in R. The figue is something [like this](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/examples/dogs/dogs.dat). As you can see from the link, the "ones" are replaced by "S" and "zeros" by ".". It's a simple graphic, but it shows each individual response by time.

Comment: Couldn't you just replace 1 with S, and 0 with .? And then print the data.frame?

Comment: Yep. But printing on R console and then just copy and paste at text editor? It doesn't sound like a good way, but maybe i'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with a formatted text output using `sprintf`. Much cleaner and simpler. If you still want a plot, you could go with the following:

Given matrix `tbl` containing your data:

```
tbl <- matrix(data=rep(0:1,25), nrow=5)
```

You can generate a plot as:

```
plot(1, 1, xlim=c(1,dim(tbl)[2]+.5), ylim=c(0.5,dim(tbl)[1]), type="n")
lapply(1:dim(tbl)[1], function(x) {
  text(x=c(1:dim(tbl)[2]), y=rep(x,dim(tbl)[2]), labels=tbl[x,])
})
```

Using this as a base you can play around with the `text` and plot `args` to stylize the plot the way you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possible solutions, based on fake data generated with this helper function:

```
generate.data <- function(rate=.3, dim=c(25,25)) {
  tmp <- rep(".", prod(dim))
  tmp[sample(1:prod(dim), ceiling(prod(dim)*rate))] <- "S"
  m <- matrix(tmp, nr=dim[1], nc=dim[2])
  return(m)
}
```

1. **Text-based output**

   ```
   x <- generate.data()
   rownames(x) <- colnames(x) <- 1:25
   capture.output(as.table(x), file="res.txt")
   ```

   The file `res.txt` include a pretty-printed version of the console output; you can convert it to pdf using any txt to pdf converter (I use the one from PDFlib). Here is a screenshot of the text file:

   [image]
2. **Image-based output**

   First, here is the plotting function I used:

   ```
   make.table <- function(x, labels=NULL) {
     # x = matrix
     # labels = list of labels for x and y
     coord.xy <- expand.grid(x=1:nrow(x), y=1:ncol(x))
     opar <- par(mar=rep(1,4), las=1)
     plot.new() 
     plot.window(xlim=c(0, ncol(x)), ylim=c(0, nrow(x)))
     text(coord.xy$x, coord.xy$y, c(x), adj=c(0,1)) 
     if (!is.null(labels)) {
       mtext(labels[[1]], side=3, line=-1, at=seq(1, ncol(x)), cex=.8)
       mtext(labels[[2]], side=2, line=-1, at=seq(1, nrow(x)), cex=.8, padj=1)
     }
     par(opar)
   }
   ```

   Then I call it as

   ```
   make.table(x, list(1:25, 1:25))
   ```

   and here is the result (save it as png, pdf, jpg, or whatever).

   [image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks all of you. I'll try all ideas and see what fits better my interests and I'll chose one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, this is a text table. I am wondering why you want to make it a graph? Anyway, quick solutions are (either way)

1. make the text table (by programming or typing) and make its screenshot and embed the image into the plot.
2. make a blank plot and put the text on the plot by programming R with "text" function. For more info on "text", refer to http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/kr_adtxt.html

Comment: In addition to screenshot the text table, it is also possible to use the `gplots::textplot` function

Comment: Hi, I know it's a text table (hence my guess that he used Latex).  But I have a data frame of my onw and don't want to transform it on text table and put in Word editor (which is what I'm using). Maybe I'm wrong here and it would be easier to produce the text table, even using MS Word. Any suggestion in this regard are very apreciated, of course. Thanks anyway.