# pixelwise rescaling of a time series using cumulative distribution function matching

Tags: r, time-series, r-raster, cdf

I'm using R and I have a raster stack of surface soil moisture measurements from a radiometer on fixed on an observation tower. These data are daily values going back 10 years.

I also have another raster stack of satellite microwave measurements of soil moisture over a larger area going back 25 years. Both sensors have similar frequencies.

On a per-pixel basis, I would like to use a linear cumulative distribution function matching that rescales the satellite data against the tower data so that it would result in a longer time series of rescale satellite data.

This point is to correct for systematic differences between the soil moisture values and extend the time series. This is similar to what was done in the figure below where they matched the AMSR-E (blue plot) and ASCAT (red plot) data to Noah data (black plot).

[image: Figure 3 in Liu et al (2011) in *Hydrol. Earth Syst. Sci.*]

Does anyone know how to implement this in R? Or at the very least help me get started? I've scoured the Internet and this website without success.

Comment: Please be specific about your question (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Unfortunately, your question is too general and not clear.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But I'm not sure how much clearer I can be. Can you please be specific about what is unclear in my question?

Comment: This is not the right place to share a paper and ask members to read and provide an implementation structure. Neither a right place to ask for subjective solutions. It is not clear what you have done regarding above and your question has zero reproducibility.

Comment: I'll try to make it reproducible and reformulate the question. For the record, the whole point is that I don't know how to do this in R and would appreciate some help, even to get me started. This type of question has been asked before in this forum and has received help. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232959/graphic-of-binary-variable-in-r